# Fix width of an animated underline on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 4 for a custom wordpress theme. I've readed this short article where is explained how to create an animated underline on hover. On desktop all works fine but on mobile the underline will take the 100% of the width under the menu elements. Is possible to fix?

here is the css code I'm using:

```
.top{
  position: relative;
  color: black;
}
.top:hover{
  color: rgb(28,67,63);
}
.top:hover:after{
  width: 100%;
}
.top:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(28,67,63);
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

To be more clear here is an image of the problem that is happening

[mobile underline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTbMY.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved using the `inline-block` display property on mobile.

```
.top{
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Try to arrange your CSS code, **.top:hover::after** must come after **.top::after**,
also, the trick that on mobile the element take the full width, so try to give the element specific width on mobile screens.

Try this code, it's work fine.

```
<div class="top">
   Hi
</div>
```

```
.top{
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  width: 50px;
}
.top::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(28, 67, 63);
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.top:hover{
  color: rgb(28, 67, 63);
}
.top:hover::after{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: but with a fixed width of `50px` there are some text element that will not fit at all. I will give your code a try.

Comment: you can set your desired width only on mobile screens, you can do it using media  queries.

Comment: I know,I already have media queries in my css, I've tested as you suggested, but this will break the text elements align from the center to the left on two lines, so it's not the ideal fix.

Comment: the code is what I've posted. on the html side I have the standard bootstrap mobile menù that will fade in from left instead of the traditional bootstrap beahviour and the `<a>` elements are aligned to center.